# 100% width of a Frame for a Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I stretch a control, say a Button, in a Frame so that a Button takes 100% of the width of a Frame? I've tried to look for that but haven't found anything that could help.

**update**

a frame in which the button is located, is created this way:

```
frame1 = Frame(....)
frame1.grid(row=0, sticky="news")
```

How can I get the button to take 100% of the width of the frame? This doesn't work:

```
btn.pack(fill=X) 
# or 
# btn.grid(sticky="ew")
```

Comment: `fill='x'` works for pack, and `sticky='ew'` works for grid. Your problem could be that the button fills the frame, but the frame isn't filling the window. Please show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

```
b = Button(my_frame, text="Submit")
b.pack(fill=X)
```

Comment: With the grid geometry manager you would use the attribute `sticky="ew"`.

Answer (score 1):

In the grid geometry manager:

```
b = Button(my_frame, text="Submit")
b.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")
```